# Substitute hyphens for camel case in vim

Tags: vim

In vim, I need to replace a hyphenated vars with camelcase vars. Some vars also have numbers after the hyphen. Is there a good substitute command for this?

**Ex:**

`this-var` becomes `thisVar`

`var-10` becomes `var10`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured out the answer if anyone needs it:

`:%s/\v%(-)([a-z])/\U\1/gc`